# Operator '-' not defined VB6 to VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, vb6, vb6-migration

Another migration question. I have a chunk of VB6 code that seems to need some workaround for .NET. For a shortened version, this is all it is doing:

```
Printer.Line (lftx * stepx * fx, k * stepy * fy)-(rgtx * stepx * fx, k * stepy * fy), RGB(77, 66, 71)
```

Keep giving me Error ID: BC30205, End of statement expected, on minus sign.

I have added a parenthesis that encloses the contents of the command, aware that it does not completely solve the problem.
Doing so a different error appears, Error ID: BC30452, Operator '-' is not defined for types '(Single, Single)' and '(Single, Single)'.
I guess it can't subtract because of the commas inside the brackets...

As you may have noticed, I never written in VB6 and im not a programmer.  How do I implement the same thing in .NET? Thank you for all the help

Comment: That was a [statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-basic-6/aa716270(v=vs.60)) in VB6 with peculiar syntax `Line (x1, y1) - (x2, y2)`. In VB.NET there is no such peculiar syntax, all methods are born equally, the compatibility shim is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb823229(v=vs.90).

Answer (score 3):

An equivalent instruction for printer.line is e.Graphics.DrawLine(). Here is a sample code that you may find [here](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/programming-visual-basic/0596000936/ch04s07.html) and to which I have added e.Graphics.DrawLine in the following code:

```
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D
Imports System.Drawing.Printing

Private Sub btnPrint_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPrint.Click
    ' ...
    ' These two lines initiate printing. Place this code in an
    ' appropriate place in the application.
    Dim pd As New HelloPrintDocument()
    pd.Print()
End Sub
' ...

' This class manages the printing process.
Public Class HelloPrintDocument
    Inherits PrintDocument

    Protected Overrides Sub OnPrintPage(ByVal e As PrintPageEventArgs)
        MyBase.OnPrintPage(e)

        ' Draw text to the printer graphics device.
        Dim fnt As New Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Regular,
           GraphicsUnit.Point)
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Hello, Printer!", fnt, Brushes.Black, 0, 0)
        Dim x0 As Int32 = 0
        Dim y0 As Int32 = 0
        Dim x1 As Int32 = 0
        Dim y1 As Int32 = 50
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, New Point(x0, y0), New Point(x1, y1))
        Dim w As Int32 = 200 ' rectangle width
        Dim h As Int32 = 50 '  rectangle height
        y0 += 12
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, New Rectangle(New Point(x0, y0), New Size(w, h)))
        y0 = e.PageBounds.Height - h * 2
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Green, New Rectangle(New Point(x0, y0), New Size(w, h)))

        fnt.Dispose()

        ' Indicate that there are no more pages.
        e.HasMorePages = False
    End Sub

End Class
```